# object HTMLImageElement apeearing from jQuery when trying to insert images

Tags: html, jquery, image

So here is what I'm trying to do:
Display a pattern that is randomly created with images, but keep getting the [object HTML Image Element] box appearing

```
var s1 = [];
    s1[0] = new Image();
    s1[0].src = '11.jpg';
    s1[1] = new Image();
    s1[1].src = '12.jpg';
    s1[2] = new Image();
    s1[2].src = '13.jpg';
    s1[3] = new Image();
    s1[3].src = '14.png';
    s1[4] = new Image();
    s1[4].src = '15.png';

    var s2 = [];
    s2[0] = new Image();
    s2[0].src = '21.jpg';
    s2[1] = new Image();
    s2[1].src = '22.jpg';
    s2[2] = new Image();
    s2[2].src = '23.jpg';
    s2[3] = new Image();
    s2[3].src = '24.png';
    s2[4] = new Image();
    s2[4].src = '25.jpg';
    
    
    var s3 = [];
    s3[0] = new Image();
    s3[0].src = '31.jpg';
    s3[1] = new Image();
    s3[1].src = '32.jpg';
    s3[2] = new Image();
    s3[2].src = '33.jepg';
    s3[3] = new Image();
    s3[3].src = '34.jpg';
    s3[4] = new Image();
    s3[4].src = '35.gif';
```

The arrays are now created, I want it to randomly pick 1 of the 5 to use, which seems to be working fine

```
    p1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
    p2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
    p3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
        
    if(p1 == 1) {
        
        p1 = s1[0];
        
        } else if (p1 == 2) {
        
        p1 = s1[1];
        
        } else if (p1 == 3) {
        
        p1 = s1[2];
        
        } else if (p1 == 4) {
        
        p1 = s1[3];
        
        } else if (p1 == 5) {
        
        p1 = s1[4];
        
        }
```

This exact same if/ else if structure is done for p2 and p3, I wont copy and paste it in to save space, now I want to output the final pattern, which is when i'm getting the object HTML image element appearing

```
while(repeat > 0){
        
            pattern = p1 + p2 + p3 + pattern;
            repeat --;
            
        
        }
        correctAnswer = 1;


    $("#patternSpan").html(pattern)
```

Comment: HTML elements cannot be concatenated like strings. You simply take the problem by the wrong end. It would be easier to have 3 static image elements inside `patternSpan` and randomly change the `src` attributes.

Comment: I didn't include it in my answer, but @LouysPatriceBessette's suggestion is better

Answer (score 0):

### Probelm

What does it mean to add images to each other?
Should all the rgb values for each pixel be added together? Should it create a new image with the pixels appended? appended to which side?

Neither of these things make sense for a language to automatically do, so whats happening here:

```
pattern = p1 + p2 + p3 + pattern;
```

Is that javascript is trying to decide if `+` means numeric addition or string concatenation.
Because the values aren't numbers, JS defaults to string concatenation.

What happens to a non-string when you attempt string concatenation?
JS calls `.toString()` on the value first

Turns out the string value for an image is `[object HTML Image Element]`

### Solution

So what you want to do is append the images to `#patternSpan`. So instead of adding the images together, append them to the span:

```
$("#patternSpan").append(p1, p2, p3)
```

---

#### Side note

The section where you randomly pick the images can be cleaned up a lot by doing this instead:

```
idx1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
idx2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
idx3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
    
p1 = s1[idx1];
p2 = s2[idx2];
p3 = s3[idx3];
```

You should also avoid re-using variables like `p1` for different types of things, ie storing a random number and storing an image.
You are more likely to run into type related bugs if a variable can contain multiple possible types.